# Call function at scroll once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery function `counter` and I need to call it when I scroll page

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.counter = function () {
        $(this).each(function () {
            var num = $(this).data('counter');
            var i = 1,
                self = $(this).html(i);
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                self.html(++i);
                if (i >= num) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var height = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(height  > 300) {
            $('.counter-1, .counter-2, .counter-3, .counter-4').counter();
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is when I scroll page again up or down function is called again and again every time.

I tried to use this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.counter = function () {
        $(this).each(function () {
            var num = $(this).data('counter');
            var i = 1,
                self = $(this).html(i);
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                self.html(++i);
                if (i >= num) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    };

    $(window).one('scroll', function () {
        var height = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (height > 300) {
            $('.counter-1, .counter-2, .counter-3, .counter-4').counter();
        }
    });

});
```

but in this case after the reloading the page function is not called.

Is there any way to call function only once on scroll and don't call it again but call it after the reloading the page ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a name space with `.on/.off` :

```
$(window).on('scroll.custom', function () {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (height > 300) {
        $('.counter-1, .counter-2, .counter-3, .counter-4').counter();
        $(window).off('scroll.custom')
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried someting like this http://jsfiddle.net/u6pah/2/. but why u use `scroll.custom`, but not just `scroll` ?

Comment: @truslivii.lev because i don't know if you have any other `window.scroll` event. It is just a security since without name space, you'd remove every scroll event on the window.

Comment: By the way, your fiddle is not working since you have no scrollbar (so can't really trigger scroll event or have a scroll higher than 300) : http://jsfiddle.net/u6pah/3/

Comment: but I will use my script not on fiddle ;)